# Can I make the Azure Application Gateway act as a forward proxy?

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-application-gateway

I want to use the IP address of the Azure Application Gateway to use for outgoing traffic that comes from internal services and not the ones of the services. Basically I want to use the GW to act on behalf of the services - act as a forward proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not possible at the moment. The Application gateway is designed to work as a reverse proxy and not a forward proxy.

The alternative to which would be to use any of the below:

1. Azure ELB - If you are not looking for

   - cookie persistence
   - WAF capabilites
   - ssl offloading
   - ssl strengthening (use certain versions of tls and ciphers)
   - encrypt application cookie
   - disable headers (Server, X-Powered-By)
   - disable clickjacking (x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN)
   - block blacklisted user agents
   - cookie encryption
   - schedule maintenance redirect to a webpage during a maintenance window
   - redirect HTTP error 403 to 404
   - restrict outside access to certain pages

** Most of which you can do over new Application gateway and Azure Firewall

3. 3rd Party load balancers - F5, NetSclaer etc..
4. Use Ngnix, "best option" Resume complete control over load balancing.
5. Firewall of your choice with these capabilities

Reference Links:
https://kemptechnologies.com/load-balancing-nginx/microsoft-azure/
https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/12/netscaler-cache-redirection-gen-wrapper-10-con/cache-redirection-config/configure-forward-proxy-redirection.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq